# C++ Create ThreadPool (Like java)

Tags: c++, threadpool

I got an problem, im programing an antihack program but i dont have idea how to repeat an function every x time like ThreadPool in java.
I think something like that:

```
while(true)
{
    //Bad Procces its def before
    if(badprocces())
        ExitApplication(1);
}
//Other code there
```

But the other code not gona to be runned because the while dont allow it.

Else i think something like that:

```
while(true)
{
//Bad Procces its def before
    if(badprocces())
        ExitApplication(1);
    if(anotherCheck())
        ExitApplication(1);
}
```

But i guess isn't the best way.

Its is possible? (Create a call ThreadPool like in java).
How to? (Whit example better)
Another Solution? (Better whit example)

Okay, that it's all.
Thanks for read and for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a timer like program you can make it easily like this, however I would encapsulate it in a class.

```
std::atomic_bool go(true);

std::thread t([&](){
     while(go){
         do_work();
         //wait (create a timer basically)
         std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(5) );
     }
});

//do stuff (or wait for user input)
go=false;
t.join();
```

If you don't have C++11 support than you can use the boost alternatives with lambdas.

I aren't certain whether or not the automatic variable is strictly necessary.

It should be noted that this is not a thread pool but a single thread that loops with wait.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at all convinced that this particular problem actually *needs* a thread pool ...
... but if you want one, I encourage you to look at this library:

- http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/

Some general rules of thumb:

- If you don't have a clearly defined task that lends itself to threading (like handling an internet download, for example), then don't use threads.
- If you can block ("suspend" until some "event") instead instead of cycling in a "sleep/check" loop, then block.  Polling is Evil.  Blocking is Good.
- The only reason you'd want a "thread pool" is if you expect a lot of small tasks to quickly, randomly come and go.  The advantage (AFAIK the *only* real advantage) of a "thread pool" is to avoid the overhead of creating and destroying threads (by re-using existing threads for new tasks).  In most scenarios, the benefits of simplifying your code (by simply creating threads as-needed) far outweighs in benefit in setting up, managing and using a thread pool.

IMHO...